# jquerymobile and asp.net mvc 3 has navbar in popup dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuerymobile and one of my links has the data-rel="dialog" attribute which launches my page in a dialog. However I noticed that the page that is launched has the navbar from the main page together with the header.

Any ideas why this is happening?

My _layout.cshtml is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /navbar -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
</div>
<!-- /page -->
```

and the index.cshtml is :

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { data_rel = "dialog" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", null, new { data_rel = "dialog" })</li>
</ul>
```

and about.cshtml is:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
}

<h2>About</h2>
<p>
     Put content here.
</p>
```

SO I get About.cshtml show as a dialog popup but with the header and navbar shown in it as well (I do not want this shown).

Answer (score 1):

_layout.cshtml is loaded by default for each viewpage. To override this behaviour try to inlcude something like this your about.cshtml:

```
@{
     Layout = "~/_dialogLayout.cshtml";
 }
```

or to have no layout page loaded at all

```
@{
     Layout = "";
 }
```

Comment: Hi Mark, unfortunately setting layout = "" gives me a dialog with the word undefined in it (just about work it out).

Comment: Okay, got it working. Thanks for the code above. I was trying to make all this work with mvc 2 code and was not aware of layout. I added a data-role="header" to my about.cshtml form and all works. Thanks once again.